# Sign of 3j symbol (in view of interpolation)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, interpolation

**Question**

Is there a closed formula for the sign of a 3j symbol?

**Context**

I need to compute Wigner 3J symbols/Clebsch–Gordan coefficients,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\ell_1 &\ell_2 &\ell_3\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix} ,
$$

for all configurations of ($\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$) up to $\ell_\text{max}\sim 2000$. Speed is crucial so rather than computing the 3j a billion times, I would resort to an interpolation scheme.

The raw 3j symbol is impervious to interpolation as it continuously alternates from negative to positive values; for example, consider this plot of the 3j coefficients as a function of $\ell_3$ with $\ell_1=120$ and $\ell_2=90$:

[image: 3j symbol with l1=120, l2=90]
<sub>(source: [guidowalterpettinari.eu](http://www.guidowalterpettinari.eu/external_access/3j.png))</sub>

The absolute value of the 3j, on the other hand, is much smoother:

[image: absolute value of the 3j symbol with l1=120, l2=90]
<sub>(source: [guidowalterpettinari.eu](http://www.guidowalterpettinari.eu/external_access/3j_absolute.png))</sub>

My plan is to interpolate the absolute value of the 3j symbol, and assign the sign only after the interpolation. Hence the question: is there a closed formula for the sign of a 3j symbol?

**EDIT:**

The question has been answered thanks to Gjergji Zaimi. I am now looking into the same problem but with a more general 3J symbol,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\ell_1 &\ell_2 &\ell_3\\
0&m&-m
\end{pmatrix} .
$$

Please feel free to have a look at the corresponding [Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/222319/47396).

Comment: Could you plot something like http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0703104.pdf and included sources as well? Then you can judge whether you are using large enough j's for that asymptotic to be useful.

Comment: @AHusain, thanks for the suggestion! I Do you have in mind a specific equation? Maybe eq. 112 on pag. 36? Please forgive me, but it is quite a long paper and I am not an expert in the field.

Comment: Yes. That's the one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wigner3j-Symbol.html) contains the following formula which should make your calculations easy:

> If $\ell_1+\ell_2+\ell_3=2g$ then $$\begin{pmatrix}
> \ell_1 &\ell_2 &\ell_3\\
> 0&0&0
> \end{pmatrix}=$$
>   $$(-1)^g\sqrt{\frac{(2g-2\ell_1)!(2g-2\ell_2)!(2g-2\ell_3)!}{(2g+1)!}}\frac{g!}{(g-\ell_1)!(g-\ell_2)!(g-\ell_3)!}$$
>   and if $\ell_1+\ell_2+\ell_3=2g+1$ then $\begin{pmatrix}
> \ell_1 &\ell_2 &\ell_3\\
> 0&0&0
> \end{pmatrix}=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much Gjergjj! This is exactly what I was looking for. I am now looking into the same problem but with $m\neq0$; please feel free to have a look at my [new question on Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/222319/47396).